# Reference Meteor.user() in Ionic2 / Angular2 html

Tags: meteor, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm in a *Ionic2* project using *Meteor*.

In my Component I declare *Meteor* with `declare let Meteor;`.

After that I can get the user with `Meteor.user();` within my source-code.

But I'm not able to to the same in my html-code `*ngIf="Meteor.userId()` or `{{Meteor.user().username}}`.

I get the error `Cannot read property 'userId' of undefined`.

Can someone tell me how to access *Meteor* in the html-source? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
...
declare let Meteor;

export class NewMyPage {
   M = Meteor;
...
...
```

After that I can user `*ngIf="M.userId()` or `{{M.user().username}}` in my html-source.